# How to show the last li in list on jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My javascript code is like this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myList li:lt(3)').show();
    var items =  $('ul#myList li').length
    var shown =  3;
    
    if(items <= 3)
         $('#loadMore').hide();
         
    $('#loadMore').click(function () {
        shown = $('#myList li:visible').length+5;
        if(shown < items) {
            $('#myList li:lt('+shown+')').show();
        }
        else {
            $('#myList li:lt('+items+')').show();
            $('#loadMore').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Demo and full code is like this : http://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/nFd7C/1085/

When the code executed, it will display this :

> One
>
> Two
>
> Three

It will display three item first

But I want dislay three item last

So I want the result like this :

> Twenty three
>
> Twenty four
>
> Twenty five

How can I do it?

Comment: Why did Question receive "downvote"?

Comment: @guest271314, I do not know. Another user who downvote. I can not refuse it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.slice()` with parameter `-3` to select last three elements of jQuery object;

```
$("#myList li").slice(-3).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `slice`

```js
   $(document).ready(function() {
  var slice = -3;
  $('#myList li').slice(slice).show();
  var items = $('ul#myList li').length
  var shown = 3;

  if (items <= 3)
$('#loadMore').hide();

  $('#loadMore').click(function() {
slice = slice - 5;
if (shown < items) {
  $('#myList li').slice(slice).show();
  if ($('ul#myList li:visible').length == items)
    $('#loadMore').hide();
}
  });
});
```

```css
#myList li {
  display: none;
  list-style-type: none;
}

#loadMore {
  color: green;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#loadMore:hover {
  color: black;
}

#showLess {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#showLess:hover {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="myList">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
  <li>Six</li>
  <li>Seven</li>
  <li>Eight</li>
  <li>Nine</li>
  <li>Ten</li>
  <li>Eleven</li>
  <li>Twelve</li>
  <li>Thirteen</li>
  <li>Fourteen</li>
  <li>Fifteen</li>
  <li>Sixteen</li>
  <li>Seventeen</li>
  <li>Eighteen</li>
  <li>Nineteen</li>
  <li>Twenty one</li>
  <li>Twenty two</li>
  <li>Twenty three</li>
  <li>Twenty four</li>
  <li>Twenty five</li>
</ul>
<div id="loadMore">Load more</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the following;

`$('#myList li:gt(-4)').show();`

It will be showing the last three children.

http://jsfiddle.net/nFd7C/1086/

It is kind of an hack of the logic, but works.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to go about this would be to invert the list with jQuery just before limiting the shown items to 3:

```
$('ul > li').each(function() {
  $(this).prependTo(this.parentNode);
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('ul > li').each(function() {
    $(this).prependTo(this.parentNode);
  });

  $('#myList li:lt(3)').show();
  var items = $('ul#myList li').length
  var shown = 3;

  if (items <= 3)
    $('#loadMore').hide();

  $('#loadMore').click(function() {
    shown = $('#myList li:visible').length + 5;
    if (shown < items) {
      $('#myList li:lt(' + shown + ')').show();
    } else {
      $('#myList li:lt(' + items + ')').show();
      $('#loadMore').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#myList li {
  display: none;
  list-style-type: none;
}

#loadMore {
  color: green;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#loadMore:hover {
  color: black;
}

#showLess {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#showLess:hover {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="myList">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
  <li>Six</li>
  <li>Seven</li>
  <li>Eight</li>
  <li>Nine</li>
  <li>Ten</li>
  <li>Eleven</li>
  <li>Twelve</li>
  <li>Thirteen</li>
  <li>Fourteen</li>
  <li>Fifteen</li>
  <li>Sixteen</li>
  <li>Seventeen</li>
  <li>Eighteen</li>
  <li>Nineteen</li>
  <li>Twenty one</li>
  <li>Twenty two</li>
  <li>Twenty three</li>
  <li>Twenty four</li>
  <li>Twenty five</li>
</ul>
<div id="loadMore">Load more</div>
```

This way when you click on 'Load more', you correctly reverse through the elements, until you've reached element one :)

I've also created a fiddle demonstrating this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/y3t0hd74/).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using "GT" in your selector instead, like this...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var items =  $('ul#myList li').length;
  var shown = 3;
  var start = items-shown-2; //account for 0-indezing
  $('#myList li:gt('+start+')').show();
//.....
```

Answer (score 0):

Selecting only the last three items can be done by doing :gt(-4)

**Example**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("tr:gt(-4)").css("background-color", "yellow");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Welcome to My Web Page</h1>

<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Königlich Essen</td>
    <td>Philip Cramer</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>North/South</td>
    <td>Simon Crowther</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I modified https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_sel_gt while finding this selector.